# PHP - How can I nest a while loop inside an if isset condition?

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

I have this table element with the following code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    if (strlen($cIdMsg = 0) && strlen($cFirstNameMsg = 0) && strlen($cLastNameMsg = 0) && strlen($pCodeMsg = 0)) {
        require_once("conn.php");
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM customer;";
        $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2)
        or die ('Problem with query' . mysqli_error($conn));
        echo "no errors found";
    }
}
?>

<table>
<tr>
    <th>Customer ID</th>
    <th>FIrst Name</th>
    <th>Last Name </th>
</tr>

<?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["customerID"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["firstName"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["lastName"]?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Above this table I have the php code that makes the sql queries inside an if isset condition so that it only loads after pressing submit on the form. I would like to do the same to the table. That is to only make it load after pressing submit. because on page load it is trying to do the mysqli_fetch_array on a non existent $result yet

Comment: Post your full code!!

Comment: you want to use an Ajax request to get the data in the background and insert the rows only when you have the result of the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the whole table inside:

```
<?php if (isset($result)) { ?>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Customer ID</th>
    <th>FIrst Name</th>
    <th>Last Name </th>
</tr>

<?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["customerID"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["firstName"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["lastName"]?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

I have used `isset($result)` based on what you have said. You can check for the POST values by checking for `count($_POST)`, or something similar (*not a good idea to check for `isset($_POST["submit"])`*). If you are fetching for AJAX Response, it is always better to use a **different separate file** for this.

Comment: thank you this worked perfectly. May I ask why you dont recommend using, isset($_POST["submit"]), because that is what we were told to use for postback

Comment: @nanjero05 Some idiotic browsers will not send the `Submit` value, also many of the developers, forget to name the `Submit` button. Just in case. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if(mysqli_num_rows($result)!=0) { ?>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Customer ID</th>
    <th>FIrst Name</th>
    <th>Last Name </th>
</tr>

<?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["customerID"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["firstName"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["lastName"]?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```